# encode string in Python 3 without unicode \xc2 subsitution

Tags: python, string, unicode, decode, encode

So I was writing some code for some communication with a piece of hardware vis pySerial and i was using python 2.7.7 and everything worked fine, i switched to python 3.4 cause i issues with getting a GUI "framework" installed.

So the problem i have is that I have to encode and decode strings that i send to the COM port, i didn't need to on Python 2.7.7

Here is the string, i understand that the hex value 81 is not ascii but i need to send the string the way it is sent in python 2.7.7.

```
str = '\x1B\x81'
```

When i print str I get this:

```
b'\x1b\xc2\x81'
```

I assume that the \xc2 is some special unicode character for my \x81, I understand that \x is the escape character for hex and I'm not too sure how Python 2.7.7 writes the string to the serial port.

Would this line:

```
ser.write('\x1B\x81')
```

send binary to the serial port? sorta like this:

```
ser.write('0001 1011 1000 0001')
```

Also if i send this:

```
ser.write('\x1B\x81')
```

to the hardware using Python 3, the hardware just hangs and does nothing, but in Python 2.7 it works.

Comment: Have you tried making the string binary like `u'\x1B\x81'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `obj = '\x1B\x81'` in Python 2.7 would be `obj = b'\x1B\x81'` in Python 3.

The value `'\x1B\x81'` in Python 3 is text so you're not sending binary to the hardware (it's what's called a Unicode string in Python 2).

Comment: oh ok, thanks that works but i was wondering if there is a better way to send binary than putting a 'b' in front of the string?

Comment: Better in what way? For longer byte strings you can convert text to bytes using `bytes('aa', encoding='ascii')`.

Comment: like if i have this line
     `ser.write(ESCAPE + HI)`
, how do I change the line so it sends as binary, putting the b in front doesn't work. Oh i think i got it: `ser.write(bytes(ESCAPE + HI, encoding='ascii'))`

Comment: What are the types of `ESCAPE` and `HI`?

Comment: I tried the bytes thing and it didn't work, they are strings, constants. `ESCAPE = '\x1B'` and `HI='\x81'`

Comment: In that case you need to update both constants to be bytes, so `ESCAPE = b'\x1B'` and `HI=b'\x81'`. Everything that's a byte string in Python 2 needs to be bytes in Python 3 for things to work.